Use \printindex with \pagenumbering{gobble}
I'm trying to use \tableofcontents without page numbers, so I use \pagenumbering{gobble}. However, it seems I cannot use \printindex to write an index page. Here is my code:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs,mathtools,nicematrix,chngcntr,centernot,ytableau,tikz-cd}
\usepackage{textcomp,tocloft,environ,setspace,geometry,enumerate,enumitem,blindtext,multicol,xcolor,fancyhdr,calligra,graphicx,wrapfig,pgfplots,mdframed,tabularx,lipsum,comment,csquotes,imakeidx,etoolbox}

% Title page setup
\newcommand{\hsetup}{%
    \begin{center}
        \Huge\bfseries\htitle \\
        \vspace{2pt}
        \Large{\hauthor}
    \end{center} 
    \normalsize
    \vspace{-20.5pt}
    \phantom{}\hrule\phantom{}
}

% Table of Contents
\renewcommand*\contentsname{}
\newcommand{\htoc}{%
    \normalsize
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \begin{frame}{}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
          \tableofcontents
        \end{multicols}
    \end{frame}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace{-6.5pt}\phantom{}\hrule\phantom{}
}

% Mainmatter setup
\newcommand{\hmain}{%
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead[L]{\hauthor}      
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}    
    \fancyhead[C]{\htitle}             
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \fancyfoot{}
}

% Adjust the headheight
\setlength{\headheight}{13pt}

\def\htitle{Test Document}
\def\hauthor{Hello World}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\hsetup\
\htoc\
\hmain\


\section{This is a test}
index\index{index}

\section{This is a test}

\printindex

\end{document}

It looks like:
Are there any simple solutions to this problem? I don't want any page number in the table of contents and I want to use \printindex for an index page. Thanks in advance.

welcome! what exactly should the index entries point to if you don't have any page numbers? and why don't you want page numbers in your table of contents? are you concerned your readers will be too well-disposed towards your text? (maybe you're preparing this for a longstanding foe?) \pagenumbering{gobble} is a sledge hammer. if you just(!) don't want numbers in the toc, change what's written to the toc. only kill all page numbers if you really mean it.

off-topic: your preamble is ... fraught with potential problems. you should edit to include only the packages you need and ensure those are loaded in the correct order and don't conflict.

\frame is a command (a form of \fbox) so \frame{abc}  so \begin{frame}{} is like \fbox{} and boxes nothing and \end{frame} does nothing.

as in your last question you have not made it clear how you want the index to work, you only have one \index entry real indices hav emultiple entries with the same word used multiple times with a pag enumber giving a link back to each use. As your document has unnumbered pages what do you want the index to look like. Please edit your example so that  \index{index} appears in all the sections, so the index entru for index needs multiple hyperlinks, what do you want the link text to be?
